# Notation regarding Balls

Tags: notation

What is meant by the notation :

$y \in \partial B_\epsilon (x_o)$

Where B is a Ball centred at $x_0$ with radius $\epsilon$

Comment: It means that $y$ belong to the boundary of the ball centred at $x_0$ with radius $\epsilon$, i.e. to the sphere centred at $x_0$ with radius $\epsilon$.

Answer (score 3):

When you are in a normed space, with norm $\|\cdot \|$, then $$\partial B_\epsilon(x_0)=:\{x: \|x-x_0\|=\epsilon\},$$
the boundary of $B_\epsilon(x_0)$. More generally the notation $\partial E$, with $E$ a set, denotes its [boundary](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boundary_%28topology%29#Common_definitions).

Answer (score 2):

It is the boundary of the ball.